# HashMap Implementation

Tags: java, hash-map

### Purpose

I've never implemented a `HashMap` and thought it would be a good data structure exercise. I tried looking at the Java
source code as little as possible.

### Discussion

I did not decide to implement the `Map` interface explicitly because I didn't want to support every interface method (even though a decent number of methods are identical between the interface and this implementation).

The `HashMap` was made up of an array of `Entry`s. Each `Entry` is points to another `Entry` (or `null` if it's the
last `Entry` in the linked list).

Since you'd want `Entry`s distributed as equally as possible across the different index values of the internal `Entry`
array, each key's hashcode is hashed again to combat a bad hashcode (this code is from the Java 8 source code) and
eventually an index value is calculated - this index value represents the index of the internal array that the
key-value pair will exist under.

Thus, the logic for getting a value for a particular key would be to translate the key into an index value, and then
to get the first `Entry` for that index value from the internal array. And then to get the `Entry` in the linked list
with the same key (or return `null` if the linked list has been exhausted).

Another thing that was interesting to implement was array resizing. Every time `put` is called, it checks to see if array
resizing needs to occur. I resize the array if the number of objects that have been added to the array is greater than
75% of the allocated array capacity. I don't know if this is the best way to implement a resize check. When actually
resizing the array, I needed to iterate through every `Entry` and reindex the `Entry`.

Things I don't like:

- My implementation seems really messy.

  1. I don't like the `addEntry` method. I don't like it has a `boolean` return. However, I did this so that when `put`ting
     I wouldn't update the `size` when I updated a key-value pair vs. added one.
  2. I don't like how the `setEntry` method keeps the `next` value in memory before overwriting it (this was done so
     that no `Entry` in the linked list did not get reindexed).
- Is the way I'm resizing logical? I read [this article](http://coding-geek.com/how-does-a-hashmap-work-in-java/) and
  that's where I got my ideas for how to resize the internal array.

### Implementation

```
public class HashMap<K, V> {
    private int size = 0;
    private int capacity = 16;
    private Entry<K, V>[] entries = new Entry[capacity];
    private double loadFactor = 0.75;

    private static class Entry<K, V> {
        private final K key;
        private V value;
        private Entry<K, V> next = null;

        public Entry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public HashMap() {
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.size == 0;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }

    public boolean containsKey(K key) {
        Entry<K, V> matchingEntry = getMatchingEntry(key);

        return matchingEntry != null && matchingEntry.key == key;
    }

    public boolean containsValue(V value) {
        for (Entry<K, V> entry : this.entries) {
            while (entry != null && !matches(value, entry.value)) {
                entry = entry.next;
            }

            if (entry != null) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public V get(K key) {
        Entry<K, V> matchingEntry = getMatchingEntry(key);

        return matchingEntry == null ? null : matchingEntry.value;
    }

    public void put(K key, V value) {
        if (this.shouldResize()) {
            this.resize();
        }

        if (addEntry(new Entry<>(key, value), this.entries)) {
            this.size++;
        }

    }

    public void remove(K key) {
        int index = indexOf(key);
        Entry<K, V> currentEntry = this.entries[index];

        while (currentEntry != null && currentEntry.next != null && !matches(key, currentEntry.next.key)) {
            currentEntry = currentEntry.next;
        }

        if (currentEntry != null) {
            // this case can only occur if there is only one non-null entry at the index
            if (matches(key, currentEntry.key)) {
                this.entries[index] = null;
            // this case can only occur because the next entry's key matched
            } else if (currentEntry.next != null) {
                currentEntry.next = currentEntry.next.next;
            }

            this.size--;
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldResize() {
        return this.size > Math.ceil((double) this.capacity * this.loadFactor);
    }

    private void resize() {
        this.capacity = this.size * 2;

        Entry<K, V>[] newEntries = new Entry[this.capacity];
        for (Entry<K, V> entry : this.entries) {
            if (entry != null) {
                this.setEntry(entry, newEntries);
            }
        }

        this.entries = newEntries;
    }

    private void setEntry(Entry<K, V> entry, Entry<K, V>[] entries){
        Entry<K, V> nextEntry = entry.next;
        entry.next = null;

        this.addEntry(entry, entries);

        if (nextEntry != null) {
            this.setEntry(nextEntry, entries);
        }
    }

    private boolean addEntry(Entry<K, V> entry, Entry<K, V>[] entries) {
        int index = indexOf(entry.key);
        Entry<K, V> existingEntry = entries[index];

        if (existingEntry == null) {
            entries[index] = entry;
            return true;
        } else {
            while (!this.matches(entry.key, existingEntry.key) && existingEntry.next != null) {
                existingEntry = existingEntry.next;
            }

            if (this.matches(entry.key, existingEntry.key)) {
                existingEntry.value = entry.value;
                return false;
            }

            existingEntry.next = entry;
            return true;

        }
    }

    private Entry<K, V> getMatchingEntry(K key) {
        Entry<K, V> existingEntry = this.entries[indexOf(key)];

        while (existingEntry != null && !matches(key, existingEntry.key)) {
            existingEntry = existingEntry.next;
        }

        return existingEntry;
    }

    private int indexOf(K object) {
        return object == null ? 0 : hash(object) & (this.capacity - 1);
    }

    private boolean matches(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return (o1 == null && o2 == null) ||
                (o1 != null && o2 != null && o1.equals(o2));
    }

    /**
     * Applies a supplemental hash function to a given hashCode, which
     * defends against poor quality hash functions.  This is critical
     * because HashMap uses power-of-two length hash tables, that
     * otherwise encounter collisions for hashCodes that do not differ
     * in lower bits. Note: Null keys always map to hash 0, thus index 0.
     */
    private static int hash(Object key) {
        // This function ensures that hashCodes that differ only by
        // constant multiples at each bit position have a bounded
        // number of collisions (approximately 8 at default load factor).
        int h;
        return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting compilation errors when building my array of `Entry`s. I added a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` but this is maybe not the best solution. I did not want to change the original source code I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advice 1**

Below, there is no need for explicitly assigning `null` to a reference field; Java does that by default. Also, `public` from the constructor may be removed.

```
private static class Entry<K, V> {
    private final K key;
    private V value;
    // Java initializes reference fields to null by default.
    //private Entry<K, V> next = null;
    private Entry<K, V> next;

    // No point in 'public' here:
    /*public*/ Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Advice 2**

You can remove the only (and empty) constructor.

**Advice 3**

I have embedded the comments directly in code:

```
public boolean containsKey(K key) {
    return getMatchingEntry(key) != null;
    //Entry<K, V> matchingEntry = getMatchingEntry(key);
    //
    //return matchingEntry != null && matchingEntry.key == key;
}
```

**Advice 4**

```
private void resize() {
    // This looks suspicious since depending on loadFactor size may not be
    // necessarily a power of two (which would *seem* a requirement in
    // indexOf)
    //this.capacity = this.size * 2;
    this.capacity <<= 1;
    ...
}
```

Above, depending on the value of `loadFactor`, the value of `this.size` is not necessarily a power of two.

**Advice 5**

```
private boolean matches(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return Objects.equals(o1, o2);
    //return (o1 == null && o2 == null) ||
    //        (o1 != null && o2 != null && o1.equals(o2));
}
```

Note that `Objects` is plural.

Hope that helps.